# using rotateAnimation for drawLine

Tags: java, android

I am having a line that I draw it using "canvas.drawLine(250, 400 , 250 , 200, p3 )"  , I want to rotate it using the  rotateAnimation , is there away to do it ?
when I try to put the `drawLine(...)` in a method it getting no compiled...

```
import android.widget.Toast;

class Circles<Graphics> extends View
{
public Circles(Context context)
  {
      super(context);    
  }

  public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) 
  {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      //2 Circels
      Paint p1 = new Paint();
      p1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      p1.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
       Paint p2 = new Paint();
      p2.setColor(Color.RED);
      p2.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      canvas.drawCircle(250, 400, 250, p1);
      canvas.drawCircle(250, 400, 20, p2);
    //  invalidate();

      // Seconds
      final Paint p3 = new Paint();
      p3.setColor(Color.RED);
      p3.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      int b1 ; 

      Runnable seconds = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
         try {
         int seconds = 0;
     RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
                   (seconds - 1) * 6, seconds * 6,
                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
         rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
         rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
         rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    // now rotate this   canvas.drawLine(250, 400 , 250 , 200, p3 ) ; 


         } catch (Exception e) {

          }
  }

      };
  }
```

Comment: no,  you can not do that,  instead use a ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator

Comment: can you show me an example with my code ?

Comment: tried uncle google? there are zillions pages on this topic

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use animation for drawing circle line use my code.
There is an animation which only gives you interpolated time of rotate animation, so you can simply refresh the `toAngleValue` and refresh the drawing state for smoothy your line draw.

---

```
/**
 * Created by GIGAMOLE on 17.06.2015.
 */
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        startAnimation(new CustomAnimation(fromAngleValue, toAngleValue));
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    //Out values for angle circle
    private float fromAngleValue = 0f;
    private float toAngleValue = 360f;
    private float currentAngleValue;

    //Paint
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setColor(Color.RED);
            setStrokeWidth(5);
            setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Always draw arc and invalidate it in animation
        canvas.drawArc(
                new RectF(
                        50,
                        50,
                        getWidth() - 50,
                        getHeight() - 50
                ),
                fromAngleValue,
                currentAngleValue,
                false,
                paint
        );
    }

    private class CustomAnimation extends RotateAnimation {

        public CustomAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees) {
            super(fromDegrees, toDegrees);

            setDuration(3000);
            setFillAfter(true);
        }

        public CustomAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float pivotX, float pivotY) {
            super(fromDegrees, toDegrees, pivotX, pivotY);
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            currentAngleValue = interpolatedTime * toAngleValue;
            invalidate();

            //Change current value relative to animation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use esiest method which only increment value with post invalidate, but there is no features like concret duration and any kind of intelpolators.

---

```
/**
 * Created by GIGAMOLE on 17.06.2015.
 */
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    //Out values for angle circle
    private float fromAngleValue = 0f;
    private float toAngleValue = 360f;
    private float currentAngleValue;

    //Paint
    private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setColor(Color.RED);
            setStrokeWidth(5);
            setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Always draw arc and invalidate it in animation

        canvas.drawArc(
                new RectF(
                        50,
                        50,
                        getWidth() - 50,
                        getHeight() - 50
                ),
                fromAngleValue,
                currentAngleValue,
                false,
                paint
        );

        if (currentAngleValue <= toAngleValue) {
            currentAngleValue++;
            postInvalidateDelayed(1);
        }
    }

}
```